# C++ Visual Studio- settings to catch exception caused from Boost library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, exception, boost

What settings must I set in Debug -> Exceptions so that my catch statement will catch an exception arising from a boost header file? I have try-catch statements but when an exception occurs it just highlights the line of the exception and asks whether I wish to break or continue.

In Debug->exceptions I have ticked both boxes for "C++"

(C++ user unhandled is ticked, but grayed-out)

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  You can't combine tags to create concepts.  Tagging your question with `[visual]` and `[studio]` doesn't mean the same thing as tagging with `[visual-studio]`.  Always be sure to read the helpful descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: Also, you've been here two years [pick a name already](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/997112)!

Comment: just use `catch(boost::whatevertheexceptionisnamed& e) {}`

Comment: What's your catch statement? You should be ok if you are catching `boost::exception` (or one of it's subclasses) or `std::exception`. Debugger only catches unhandled exceptions (unless you told it otherwise).

Comment: Right, after looking into Visual Studio options I think you made your debugger catch exceptions when they are thrown (before they can be caught) instead of only when they are unhandled. Try doing Debug -> Exceptions -> Reset All (or unchecking "Thrown" column next to `std::exception`).